# Azure VM Scale Set - Scale In during task

Tags: azure, virtual-machines, autoscaling

This seems like a basic question but I haven't been able to find an answer googling around.

How does scale sets know that a particular VM has finished what it's doing and is able to be de-provisioned?

From the [scale sets FAQ](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/virtual-machine-scale-sets-faq#top-frequently-asked-questions-for-scale-sets)  the VMs with the highest IDs are removed first. It doesn't say anything about whether it is mid-task or not.

This is important for my application because my tasks are long running (about 30 minutes on a 1CPU/4GB machine).

Answer (score 1):

To answer my own question, this is called "instance protection" and seems to be a common thing for long running operations.

[Scale set instance protection](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/virtual-machine-scale-sets-instance-protection#protect-from-scale-in)